# Tags' shadow design

Tags: discussion, design, tags

When you put mouse cursor over a tag, some kind of shadow appears, and I don't like it.

One of the suggestions of new design may be:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Umm... post your suggestions or proofs that the current design is the best possible.

Comment: +1 the blocky shadow seems unpolished and distracts me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the drop shadow on the right is thicker is because it's the boxshadow of the div that contains the tag. I have to shift the shadow over to the right more so the left shadow starts where the flat edge begins. Visually I agree with you. but technically I wasn't able to implement it. I'm open to suggestions of course since there are plenty css gurus on this site.

Comment: Just shift the rectangle's position right by 2px and decrease its width by 2px or 4px (if you change by 4px, the result will be as shown in my picture; if you change the width by 2px, just the one pixel (or is it better to say 2x2 pixels?) to the left will be removed). Well, I'm not even sure whether you're using rectangles...

Comment: if you use firebug you can see how i did the tags. the boxshadow has the same dimension as the div.

Comment: Ah, now I see...