# Tags seem to have too much padding on the right side

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Tags seem to have too much padding on the right side.  This is best illustrated when put in parentheses:

([example-tag](/questions/tagged/example-tag))

You can see the gap between the tag and the right paren that doesn't exist between the tag and the left paren.

This could be solved by reducing the `padding-right` for `a.post-tag` in the CSS, but that would screw up tag lists that look better with a gap, e.g.:

[tag-one](/questions/tagged/tag-one)[tag-two](/questions/tagged/tag-two)

I haven't looked at whether tag lists on questions rely on the gap, so that might be a non-issue.  If it is a problem though, my proposed solution would be to decrease the right padding slightly and increase the left padding slightly.  You can have even spacing around the tag and still have the left+right padding provide the same gap as currently.

Repro'd on Windows 7 x64:

- Chrome 13.0.782.109 beta-m
- IE 9
- FF 5.0.1

<sub>I apologize for filling Meta with bug posts and other not-about-site-content posts today.  If there is a better alternative kindly let me know and I will do that instead.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional as there needs to be room to accomodate [the shadow of the tag on hover](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/tags-shadow-design). As demonstrating with your parenthetical example:

[image: Shadowed tag]

If that padding didn't exist, it would either overlap the parenthesis (ugly), go behind the parenthesis (ugly), or resize the line on hover (ugly).

Comment: Ah, cool.  I didn't notice.  I hate drop shadows but if it's intended then nothing for it.